# How to pass value from property file to custom annotation for field in Spring

Tags: spring

I am using Spring 4.

I have created one custom annotation like

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyElement {

    HTML_TAG htmlTag() default HTML_TAG.INPUT_TEXT;

    FindBy findBy() default FindBy.NAME;

    String valueToFind() default "";

}
```

Now in my class having `@Component` i can write like

```
@Component
@PropertySource(value = "config/${environment}/environment.properties",     ignoreResourceNotFound = false)
public class MasterCardConnectPage extends MDESBasePage {


@Value("${user.name.byName:}")
private String usernamevalue;

    @MyElement(htmlTag=HTML_TAG.INPUT, findBy=FindBy.NAME, valueToFind="${user.name.byName}")
    private MYWebElement userName;


}
```

configuration file

```
@Configuration
   @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.bdd.mdes" })
    @PropertySources({
       // we can define according to project
            @PropertySource(value =     "config/${environment}/environment.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = false)
})

@ImportResource("common-beandefs.xml")
public class TestsAnnotationConfiguration extends
            BDDSpringConfiguration {
   }
```

And **sign.in.button** is a property which is define in config.property file

it should take its value from property file but it not. Can any one help me here?

If i Print a value of it with the help of `@Value` if working.

I just want to know how we can pass the value from property file into User created annotation.