# Can SystemPropertyUtils.resolvePlaceholders get value from application.properties?

Tags: java, spring

I'm making an annotation like this

```
@Foo(resource="${foo.bar}")
```

then, I put `application.properties` file.

```
foo.bar=abcd
```

finally, I made process of an annotation. I used `SystemPropertyUtils.resolvePlaceholders` to replace `${...}` to value from `application.properties`

```
String bar = SystemPropertyUtils.resolvePlaceholders("${foo.bar}");
```

But, I couldn't get value `abcd`.

1. Is it possible to get value `abcd` from `application.properties` by using `SystemPropertyUtils.resolvePlaceholders`?
2. If it's impossible, then do you know any similar method what can get value of `application.properties` and replace `${...}` code ?

thanks

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34036588/how-to-pass-value-from-property-file-to-custom-annotation-for-field-in-spring